# How do I get WooCommerce to automatically recreate pages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I had to uninstall WooCommerce plugin (I deleted the tables it created as well) and now I reinstalled the plugin and I doesn't automatically recreate the WooCommerce Pages. Am I stuck having to manually create the pages myself? Is there a way to have it automatically regenerate the pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just had the same problem.

First uninstall the plugin. Then you have to delete all rows containing "woocommerce" in the table "wp_options" on your database. Especially "skip_install_woocommerce_pages". Now install the plugin again. The notification for automatically creating pages will pop up.

Answer (score 17):

What ended up working for me was adding ["&install_woocommerce_pages=true"](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/924900382f6a897e5d496843c6e30ba2c6913765/admin/woocommerce-admin-init.php#L146) to the Settings page URL.

Comment: Especially useful for WooCommerce 2.1, because that has no `WooCommerce > Pages` anymore. Thanks!

Comment: What worked for me was: Go to the "System Status" tab on Woocommerce, click on the "Tools" tab at the top of the page, then click the sixth option ("Install pages"). http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386746/470749

Comment: This is much simpler than database table manipulation. E.g. simply visit `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&install_woocommerce_pages=true`

Comment: On new version of WooCoomerce you can use this page to create woocommerce pages automaticly: `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-setup`

Comment: @NuriAkmanis totally right with nowadays WooCommerce and Wordpress versions. That URLs works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way to get the page-creation dialog to appear.

Simply go to WooCommerce > Pages and **unset** all of the select boxes for pages (including the shop base option).

Then if you de-activate and re-activate it will ask you whether or not you want to install the pages.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what it's supposed to. If your previous pages were deleted (but still specified in WooCommerce), then just make a dummy page. Set all the select boxes to that dummy page, THEN unset them and do the steps above, then it will work.