# How did you incorporate WooCommerce in your own WordPress theme?

Tags: templates, plugins

This has most probably been asked before, but I really need to show WooCommerce products in my template, but I don't know what hooks to add where. It's my first time working with WooCommerce.

Can anybody maybe help me out? Quick step by steps of the process are all I'm asking? And a little more advice would be **greatly** appreciated.

Also, just a URL explaining the complete process would be bonus, as I can't find anything on the net at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, Woo is integrated by the use of [shortcodes](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce-docs/user-guide/misc/shortcodes/) in pages.  This is to say, if you want a page to have the cart, create a "Cart" page and put the `[woocommerce_cart]` shortcode in the content.  In fact, Woo adds two new buttons to your WYSIWYG editor to insert the shortcodes for you!  This wouldn't be a very good standalone plugin if it required theme editing just to function.  While you can hook directly into the theme, it's not necessary - nor is it really advisable, since you may want to change themes without rewriting all your custom hooks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really didn't know what to do. You have pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know of a way to have WooCommerce recreate the shop pages for you without having to re-install the entire plugin?

Comment: Check this thread here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33713/how-do-i-get-woocommerce-to-automatically-recreate-pages